# Unable to create index after remove type in mapping in elasticsearch 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

Even after removing the type in index mapping I'm getting the following error while create index. How to solve this issue?

> [es/indices.create] failed: [mapper_parsing_exception] Failed to parse mapping [properties]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:

using the following snippet to create index.

```
FileReader file = new FileReader(resourceloader.getResource(url.toString()).getFile());
CreateIndexRequest indexRequest = CreateIndexRequest.of(b -> b.index(index).withJson(file));
boolean created = client.indices().create(indexRequest).acknowledged();
```

here the mapping I used.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "create_timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "location_code": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your initial error message -- what comes after "unsupported parameters:"? That's important info...

Comment: @octavian create_timestamp is comes first there in the error message.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is fully and correctly loaded (with regards to encoding, that should probably be UTF-8)?

Answer (score 0):

The mapping you shared is correct and compatible with Elasticsearch versions 7 and 8.

Probably there are duplicated `properties` generating inside of your code.

**To reproduce the error I run the following:**

```
PUT test_mapping
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "properties": {
        "create_timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "location_code": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**The response:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "No type specified for field [properties]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping: No type specified for field [properties]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "No type specified for field [properties]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: I haven't use any logic to populate properties. just using the json I mentioned above. I have no idea how to solve it. could you please help on it?

Comment: Hey Mohan, if you can enable the debug mode and send me the request that send to elasticsearch I can help you more